# Listbox switching more BindingList<T> collections

Tags: c#, printing, listbox, datasource, bindinglist

I developing printing application for socket printing. Application have one listview and one listbox.

In listview is list of 5 printers and each has one BindingList which contain log messages. Listbox showing log message of printer collection which is selected.

I read that replacing bindinglist parent is not recommented. Is there better way to do this?

```cs
class Printer
{
   BindingList<string> log = new BindingList<string>();
   ...

}

private void listViewPrinters_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listViewPrinters.SelectedItems)
        {
            Printer prt = getPrintersItem(item.Text);

            listBoxLog.DataSource = null;
            listBoxLog.DataSource = prt.log;
            listBoxLog.SelectedIndex = listBoxLog.Items.Count - 1;

            break; // only one printer select
        }
    }
```